How to setup Drupal in Subfolders on Subdomain using Nginx Server and Docker containers
I want to run a drupal installation on a subdirecory of a subdomain. I am using docker containers as I am running various services and through that I can stick to the same syntax and setup structure.
I run a jwilder-nginx-reverse-proxy behind which I have a plain nginx webserver on the subdomain website.domain.com (original domain redacted)
I am already accessing an index.html (website.domain.com) and a phpMyAdmin installation (website.domain.com/pma) and I now want to run several Drupal installations on website.domain.com/v22 website.domain.com/v23 etc. but I cant manage to access the subdomain-subfolders.
Those Drupal installations are drupal-fpm-alpine docker containers that have the copy of a running site from another.domain.com with adapted drupal-site-settings.php.
  v23:
    container_name: v23
    image: drupal:8.7.8-fpm-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    volumes:
      - ./html/v23:/var/www/html

  v22:
    ...

  v21:
    ...

My nginx.conf looks like this:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name website.domain.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~ \/pma/ {
        rewrite ^/pma(/.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://pma;
    }

    location /v23/ {
        location ~ / {
            try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        rewrite ^/core/authorize.php/core/authorize.php(.*)$ /core/authorize.php$1;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass v23:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
        }
    }
    #location /v22/ {
    #...
    #   fastcgi_pass v22:9000;
    #...
    #}
    #location /v21/ {
    #...
    #   fastcgi_pass v21:9000;
    #...
    #}
}


This config is an edited copy of a config of my working nginx.conf from another.domain.com where I run drupal without subfdolder - but it doesn't work. In the end I am now stuck with a downloaded index.php and 404 Not Found error on website.domain.com/v23
#2024/09/18 15:32:47 [error] 7#7: *1 directory index of "/etc/nginx/html/v23/" is forbidden, client: 172.25.0.4, server: website.domain.com, request: "GET /v23/ HTTP/1.1", host: "website.domain.com"

If I try to access the index.php itself via website.domain.com/v23/index.php it just downloads that file instead of running it via php-fpm.
Can someone direct me towards an working solution for that?

For now I switched from drupal-fpm-alpine to the standard drupal container that uses apache2 for v23/v22/...
That works but I would really prefer to know how to do it with nested nginx-proxies.
